# Is it possible to save one to many relation in one line Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

How can I save this question answer relation ship model in one line using Laravel Eloquent. If this is not possible then how to save this relation efficiently (using less line of code,purely using Eloquent ORM.)

**This is question model**

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name' ,'type'];

    public $timestamps = true;

    public function answers(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Answer');
    }
}
```

**This is answer model**

```
class Answer extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['answer'];

    public $timestamps = true;


    public function question(){

        return $this->belongsTo('App\Question');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get what is the question, BTW the function answer should be renamed to answers on plural.

Comment: Thanks answer renamed to answers.

Comment: @RehmanAkbar Can you be more specific about what you need

Comment: what is the best practice to save this answers question relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you can add an answer, you need to first have a question.

```
<?php

// Create both question and answer in one go.
Question::create(['name' => 'Who is my father?'])
    ->answers()
    ->create(['answer' => 'Darth Vader']);

// If you already have a question and want to add a new answer.
$lukesQuestion->answers()->create(['answer' => 'Darth Vader']);
```

See the documentation on [Eloquent relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method).

Answer (score 0):

This is the way the Eloquent ORM works. You cannot avoid these relationship functions if you wish to take advantage of Eloquent.

You don't have to define these methods if you wish, but then you cannot use Eloquent's functionality for relationships.

Lastly, the size of the code you need for these statements has to do with the language and not the Framework.